# PHP Array_$POST to SQL

Tags: php, sql, arrays, forms, radio-button

I am trying to get the current PHP code and insert into the database. Currently I am able to save the first name, last name, and email but unable to get the rest of my form data "gender", and "console" to be saved. Here is the code

```
<!Doctype html public>

<html>
<body>

fill out the following form:

<table border="1" cellpadding="10">
<td>
<h1> Devices owned Survey </h1>
<form action="submit_answer.php" method = "POST"> 
First Name: <br /> <input type="text" name="first" /><br />
<br />
Last Name: <br /> <input type="text" name="last" /> <br />
<br />
Email: <br /> <input type="text" name="email" /> <br />
<br />
<u>Gender</u>: <br />
<br />
<input type="radio" name="gender" value="male" /> Male<br />
<input type="radio" name="gender" value="female" /> Female <br />
<br />
<u>I Have The Following:</u> <br />
<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="console" value="Playstation3" /> Playstation 3<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="console" value="Xbox360" />  Xbox 360 <br />
<input type="checkbox" name="console" value="Wii" />  Wii <br />
<input type="checkbox" name="console" value="Iphone" />  Iphone <br />
<input type="checkbox" name="console" value="MacBook" />  MacBook <br />
<br />
<input type="submit"/>
</form>

</td>
</table>
</body>
</html>



 PHP //SUMBMIT FORM
<?php

define('DB_NAME', 'survey');
define('DB_USER', 'root');
define('DB_PASSWORD', 'XXXX');
define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');

$link = mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);

 if (!$link)
{
die('Could NOT Connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
$db_selected = mysql_select_db(DB_NAME, $link);

if (!$db_selected) 
{
die ('Cant\'t use' . DB_NAME. ':' . mysql_error());
}
echo 'Connected Sucessfully';

$first = $_POST["first"]; // Since method=”post” in the form
$last = $_POST["last"];
$email = $_POST["email"];
$gender = $_POST["gender"];
$console = $_POST["console"];


$sql = "INSERT INTO survey (first, last, email) VALUES                   
( '$_POST[first]','$_POST[last]','$_POST[email]','$_POST[gender]','$_POST[console]')";
$result = mysql_query($sql);

$result = mysql_query($sql) or die ("could not save record");

mysql_close();
?>
//Also trying to validate the form so each question is answered
```

Comment: first, dont use the deprecated mysql functions, use PDO or mysqli instead. second, this had a high risk SQL vulnerability..

Comment: Have you checked the radios before submiting ? - edit - take care of injection

Comment: @reik: not at "high risk". it's flat out BEGGING for an injection attack.

Comment: @Marc B. yes, directly using unvalidated data from $_POST or $_GET is a big no. thought the TS must realize this or else it's a disaster waiting to happen.

Comment: Looks like you want to let them select more than one console? Then you need to set the name to "console[]" instead of console, and then $_POST['console'] will be an array of the selected consoles. From there you can either insert them into the DB as a CSV or do it on a joined table

Comment: is this done in my form "console[]" or within the PHP script

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method you're using to save data to your DB is extremely risky.  You're open to SQL injection attacks.  That being said, you should read up on SQL injection attacks with `mysql_query`.

I'm not going to rewrite your code completely to fix the SQL injection vulnerabilities, but to fix the problem you're currently having...

In your code you have:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO survey (first, last, email) VALUES                   
( '$_POST[first]','$_POST[last]','$_POST[email]','$_POST[gender]','$_POST[console]')";
```

You're specifying 3 columns, but passing in 5 columns.  You need to add the other 2 columns

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO survey (first, last, email, gender, console) VALUES                   
( '$_POST[first]','$_POST[last]','$_POST[email]','$_POST[gender]','$_POST[console]')";
```

But seriously, change your code!

EDIT:

If you want to take an array of `$_POST['console']` and turn it into a string that has comma separated values, try this:

Add array brackets to your `name` attribute:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="console[]" value="Playstation3" /> Playstation 3<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="console[]" value="Xbox360" />  Xbox 360 <br />
<input type="checkbox" name="console[]" value="Wii" />  Wii <br />
<input type="checkbox" name="console[]" value="Iphone" />  Iphone <br />
<input type="checkbox" name="console[]" value="MacBook" />  MacBook <br />
```

Iterate array and append values to a string:

```
<?PHP
$consoleArray = $_POST['console'];
$consoleCommaString = "";
if ($consoleArray != null && is_array($consoleArray)) {
    foreach ($consoleArray as $consoleValue) {
        $consoleCommaString .= $consoleValue .", ";
    }
}

$sql = "INSERT INTO survey (first, last, email, gender, console) VALUES ('$_POST[first]','$_POST[last]','$_POST[email]','$_POST[gender]','$consoleCommaString')";
?>
```

Comment: I am currently trying to learn PHP, and have read about that often, but am just trying to get this to work. when you mean add two colums is this done in the database.

Comment: This has been changed, but when I try to click on more then one option for the console, I am only able to have one answer and not multiple answer saved in the database.

Comment: Does your `survey` table have a column name `gender` and `console`?  If not, you will need to add them to your table structure.  In the INSERT statement you define a list of columns and then a list of values that go in those columns.  In your list of columns you only have 3 columns listed but 5 values listed.  I fixed it so there are 5 columns listed and 5 values listed.

Comment: I have both gender, and console saved in my table survey. When I run the form, I am trying to have more then one choice saved into the database for example console = playstation3, xbox360, iphone,wii,macbook. currently gender is saved as either female or male.

Comment: Take a look at my edited answer.  I think that would do what you want.  It will take the checkboxes as an array and then create a single string with the values comma separated.

Comment: It does not seem to work, the application outputs show connected, but when I open the data base nothing has been inserted, I have changed my code to reflect value consoe[]. and also have add the PHP script.

Comment: THe above code works, with adding the value into an array on the form, and then creating an array that will take and display, and save all data to the sql in string form. This was a great solution, thank you very much ADAM PLOCHER